# Django Pedigree Table

Tags: python, django

I am in the process of creating a site with Django for my wife and her dog club. I've seen many projects in php but none in python.

I'm up for tackling this in any direction!

I am wanting to dynamically create a table like this:
[image]

My model looks like such (simplified for the question):

```
class Dogs(models.Model):
    did = models.IntegerField(blank=true, null=true)
    name = models.TextField(db_column='name', blank=true, null=true)
    sire = models.TextField(db_column='Sire', blank=true, null=true) 
    dam =  models.TextField(db_column='Dam', blank=true, null=true)
```

I've created a few different recursive functions that do correctly determine the ancestors of a child, but I am having difficulty outputting in a meaningful manner.

Example:

```
dog = []
def pedigree(did, max):
    con = sqlite3.connect('dog.sqlite3')
    con.row_factory
    cursor = con.execute('SELECT "Call Name", ROUND(((JulianDay("now") - JulianDay("Date of Birth"))/365.25),1), "Sex" FROM dogs where did IS %s ' % did).fetchall()
    for row in cursor:
        name, age, gender = row[0], row[1], row[2]
    sql = "SELECT a.Sire, a.Dam, s.'Registered Name', d.'Registered Name' FROM dogs a INNER JOIN dogs s ON a.Sire = s.did INNER JOIN dogs d ON a.Dam = d.did WHERE a.did = "

    printTree(sql, did, name, 0, max)

    return dog

def printTree(stmt, did, name, N, max):
    rspan = 2**(max-N)

    if (rspan > 1):
        #print('rowspan= ', rspan, name)
        dog.append({'name': name, 'rspan': rspan})
        #dog.append(name)


    if(N < max):
        con = sqlite3.connect('dog.sqlite3').execute(stmt+str(did)).fetchall()
        for row in con:
            s, d, sn, dn = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]
        printTree(stmt, s, sn, N+1, max)
        printTree(stmt, d, dn, N+1, max)
```

The rspan was for rowspan, as I was attempting to duplicate some php projects.
The dog list would look like this:

```
{'name': 'Son', 'rspan': 8}
{'name': 'Father', 'rspan': 4}
{'name': 'Fathers Grandfather', 'rspan': 2}
{'name': 'Fathers Grandmother', 'rspan': 2}
{'name': 'Mother', 'rspan': 4}
{'name': 'Mothers Grandfather', 'rspan': 2}
{'name': 'Mothers Grandmother', 'rspan': 2}
```

I would very much appreciate any guidance that could assist! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer yet, but i am working on the exact same issue as I am porting an existing PHP app to Django.
You can see an example pedigree [here](https://www.dogtec.com/kennel/noatak/picped/cypher/gens/5).
First, you can use self joins for parents and joins to breed, kennel and breeder tables:

```
class Dog(SlugMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    kenn = models.ForeignKey(
    'Kennel', models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='kennel', db_column='kennel_id',
    related_name='dogs')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[
                       ('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')])
    birth_year = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_leader = models.BooleanField()
    weight = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    breed = models.ForeignKey(Breed, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    father = models.ForeignKey(
    'self', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name='father_offsprings')
    mother = models.ForeignKey(
    'self', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name='mother_offsprings')
    breeder = models.ForeignKey(
    'Musher', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    ....
```

<s>Then to retrieve the data, you can use raw queries rather than cursors, which gives you more structured queryset while getting the data in just one query (within the limit of I believe 32 joins in mysql)</s>

Here is the function to generate the raw query, note that it uses a stored procedure to retrieve the breeder's info:

```
def get_pedigree_query(max_gen=5):
    count = 0

    def get_from_clause(str, gen, alias, max_gen):
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
        i = count
        alias = alias if i == 1 else f"{alias}{i-1}"

        str += f"""
LEFT JOIN dog f{i}  ON {alias}.father_id = f{i}.id
LEFT JOIN dog m{i}  ON {alias}.mother_id = m{i}.id"""

        if gen < max_gen - 1:
            str = get_from_clause(str, gen + 1, 'f', max_gen)
            str = get_from_clause(str, gen + 1, 'm', max_gen)
        return str

    _select = "d.id, d.name, d.birth_year, d.is_leader, d.sex, d.slug, d.image_id, d.image_url, getDogBreeder(d.breeder_id) dog_breeder, getDogKennelSlug(d.kennel_id) kennel_slug"
    for i in range(1, 2**(max_gen-1)):
        _select += f", f{i}.id, f{i}.name, f{i}.birth_year, f{i}.is_leader, f{i}.sex, f{i}.slug, f{i}.image_id, f{i}.image_url, getDogBreeder(f{i}.breeder_id) f_dog_breeder_{i}, getDogKennelSlug(f{i}.kennel_id) f_kennel_slug_{i}, m{i}.id, m{i}.name, m{i}.birth_year, m{i}.is_leader, m{i}.sex, m{i}.slug, m{i}.image_id, m{i}.image_url, getDogBreeder(m{i}.breeder_id) m_dog_breeder_{i}, getDogKennelSlug(m{i}.kennel_id) m_kennel_slug_{i}"

    sql = f"SELECT {_select}"
    _from = get_from_clause('dog d', 1, 'd', max_gen)
    _from += "\ninner join kennel k on d.kennel_id = k.id"
    sql += f"\nFROM {_from}"
    sql += f"\nWHERE d.kennel_id = %s AND d.slug = %s AND d.is_active = 1 and k.is_active = 1"
    return sql
```

For the dog featured in the link above, the generated SQL is:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, d.birth_year, d.is_leader, d.sex, d.slug, d.image_id, d.image_url, getDogBreeder(d.breeder_id) dog_breeder, getDogKennelSlug(d.kennel_id) kennel_slug
, f1.id, f1.name, f1.birth_year, f1.is_leader, f1.sex, f1.slug,
f1.image_id, f1.image_url, getDogBreeder(f1.breeder_id) f_dog_breeder_1,
getDogKennelSlug(f1.kennel_id) f_kennel_slug_1, m1.id, m1.name,
m1.birth_year, m1.is_leader, m1.sex, m1.slug, m1.image_id,
m1.image_url, getDogBreeder(m1.breeder_id) m_dog_breeder_1,
getDogKennelSlug(m1.kennel_id) m_kennel_slug_1
, f2.id, f2.name, f2.birth_year, f2.is_leader, f2.sex, f2.slug,
f2.image_id, f2.image_url, getDogBreeder(f2.breeder_id) f_dog_breeder_2,
getDogKennelSlug(f2.kennel_id) f_kennel_slug_2, m2.id, m2.name,
m2.birth_year, m2.is_leader, m2.sex, m2.slug, m2.image_id,
m2.image_url, getDogBreeder(m2.breeder_id) m_dog_breeder_2,
getDogKennelSlug(m2.kennel_id) m_kennel_slug_2
, f3.id, f3.name, f3.birth_year, f3.is_leader, f3.sex, f3.slug,
f3.image_id, f3.image_url, getDogBreeder(f3.breeder_id) f_dog_breeder_3,
getDogKennelSlug(f3.kennel_id) f_kennel_slug_3, m3.id, m3.name,
m3.birth_year, m3.is_leader, m3.sex, m3.slug, m3.image_id,
m3.image_url, getDogBreeder(m3.breeder_id) m_dog_breeder_3,
getDogKennelSlug(m3.kennel_id) m_kennel_slug_3
FROM dog d
LEFT JOIN dog f1  ON d.father_id = f1.id
LEFT JOIN dog m1  ON d.mother_id = m1.id
LEFT JOIN dog f2  ON f1.father_id = f2.id
LEFT JOIN dog m2  ON f1.mother_id = m2.id
LEFT JOIN dog f3  ON m2.father_id = f3.id
LEFT JOIN dog m3  ON m2.mother_id = m3.id
inner join kennel k on d.kennel_id = k.id
WHERE d.kennel_id = %s AND d.slug = %s AND d.is_active = 1 and k.is_active = 1
```

You can for example access a dog's great grandmother with:

```
p = get_pedigree_query(3)
d = Dog.objects.raw(p, [27, 'cypher'])[0]
print(d.mother.mother.mother)

>>>HAWAII-1994 J. Philip, Noatak Kennels
```

Now for printing the pedigree, having the data in Django ORM objects should help. In my own project, I am still trying to decide if I will port the code from the example of the link above, or use a JS library to generate either HTML5 or SVG graphics. That could be a followup question I guess.

UPDATE 2020-06-24
With the above solution, I ran into MySQL 61 joins limit for 5+ generations pedigrees, an I found that MySQL version 8+ now supports recursive CTE queries. A simplified query would be:

```
WITH RECURSIVE ped_cte (
  gen,
  `path`,
  id,
  `name`,
  slug,
  kennel_slug,
  father_id,
  mother_id
) AS
(SELECT
  1 AS gen,
  CAST(NULL AS CHAR(255)) AS `path`,
  d.id,
  d.`name`,
  d.slug,
  getDogKennelSlug(kennel_id) AS kennel_slug,
  d.father_id,
  d.mother_id
FROM
  dog d
  INNER JOIN kennel AS k
    ON d.kennel_id = k.id
WHERE  k.slug = %s AND d.slug = %s
UNION
ALL
SELECT
  gen + 1,
  CONCAT_WS('__', `path`, 'father') AS `path`,
  f.id,
  f.name,
  f.slug,
  getDogKennelSlug(f.kennel_id) AS kennel_slug,
  f.father_id,
  f.mother_id
FROM
  ped_cte
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dog AS f
    ON ped_cte.father_id = f.id
WHERE gen <= %s
UNION
ALL
SELECT
  gen + 1,
  CONCAT_WS('__', `path`, 'mother') AS `path`,
  m.id,
  m.name,
  m.slug,
  getDogKennelSlug(m.kennel_id) AS kennel_slug,
  m.father_id,
  m.mother_id
FROM
  ped_cte
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dog AS m
    ON ped_cte.mother_id = m.id
WHERE gen <= %s)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ped_cte;
```

The query builds a materialized path field (path) which later will allow us to load the data into the object. Note that the path field has be cast to a defined width in the first iteration in order to persist in the recursion. Next step is to execute the query using a cursor. First we need the helper function from Django's documentation to return the results as a dict:

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

Then the function to execute the query given a kennel and a dog slug, and recursively load the data into the father and mother objects. Note that materialized path field is saved in the object so that we will be able to use it when we write a custom template tag for pedigree output.

```
def get_pedigree(kenn_slug, slug, max_gen):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(SQL, [kenn_slug, slug, max_gen, max_gen])
        dogs = dictfetchall(cursor)

    db_dog = next(item for item in dogs if item["path"] == None)
    dog = Dog()
    for attr, value in db_dog.items():
        setattr(dog, attr, value)

    def fill_dog(dog, prefix, gen, max_gen):
        db_dog = next(
            item for item in dogs if item["path"] == prefix + 'father')
        father = Dog()
        for attr, value in db_dog.items():
            setattr(father, attr, value)
        setattr(dog, 'father', father)

        db_dog = next(
            item for item in dogs if item["path"] == prefix + 'mother')
        mother = Dog()
        for attr, value in db_dog.items():
            setattr(mother, attr, value)
        setattr(dog, 'mother', mother)

        if gen < max_gen:
            fill_dog(dog.father, prefix + 'father__', gen+1, max_gen)
            fill_dog(dog.mother, prefix + 'mother__', gen+1, max_gen)
        return dog

    dog = fill_dog(dog, '', 1, max_gen)
    return dog
```

Comment: Excellent! You've for sure helped me on my path (and also reminded me how weak I am in sql).
Most likely I will be asking another question on displaying but I'd like to give it a try or two first.
Thanks again! Much help!

Comment: Great, let's keep ourselves updated of what we do for visualization..

Comment: Would you mind if I emailed you a question or two? I am struggling with some of the sql here. Namely the alias stuff and what is being passed to the get_from_clause

Comment: I don't think there is private messaging in so,  but you can contact me though the website from the link I provided. If your questions are relevant to the post, this is what these comments are for I believe though.

Comment: For my attempts 'd' returns something of type "class 'django.db.models.query.RawQuerySet'"
If I try to print 'd' I get:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

If I output the final sql, copy/paste into a variable, 'sq', and attempt something like:
for p in Dogs.objects.raw(sq):        
        print(p)

Then the only output is the first dog's name; no family.
Could this be because I am not using ForeignKeys?
Quick link to my model and attempted code
https://pastebin.com/FaNnufCj

Comment: Yes, the code that I provided works with foreign keys to self, you would have to adapt it if you are not using foreign keys. If you don't use foreign keys, it seem hard to enforce consistency when the same dog is used multiple times for breeding.

Comment: Smooth! I was never able to duplicate the previous example and I can see for this one I'll need to migrate my db from sqllite3 to MySQL. For the time being, my super hack job is writing the html table in Python function and outputting as a list.

Comment: Yes this is a much cleaner solution and fast. A single query for all data needed for a 5 generations pedigree executes in 3 to 5 ms on my laptop,  out of a 30K dogs database.

Answer (score 0):

view:

```
 class BiewerdbDetailView(generic.DetailView):
     model = Biewer
     context_object_name = 'dog'
```

Template:

```
{{ dog.sire.sire.dam.dam.dam.titles }}
```

dog.sire - gen name, if add dog.sire.FieldName get value of dog.sire
every next sire/dam get next gen of pedigree. +1